# How to access built-in media player opened by a UIWebView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiwebview

Currently, when a user clicks play button on the video player which is located at a webpage which is opened inside my UIWebView, built-in media player pops-up and covers entire screen.

I'm looking for a way to access that particular movie player instance so I can interact with it.

Is it something doable? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to create UIButton to run javascript code. For example, below I created a function to control play/pause youtube video.

```
- (void)clickPlayButton {
    NSString *jsCode = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementsByClassName('ytp-play-button')[0].click()"];
    [myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: jsCode];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this is not what I'm looking for. I'm already able to manipulate HTML inside a UIWebView. However, what I want to achieve is being able to access media player instance.